# /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Generating above error while working with wicked_pdf for creating pdf from html in rails in production

This is my code in controller

```
render pdf: "Project_#{Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y").gsub(',','').gsub(' ','_')}.pdf",
 #:show_as_html => true,
 template: "work_orders/print_trade.pdf.erb",
 orientation: 'Landscape',
 page_size: 'Legal',
 wkhtmltopdf: '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf',

margin: {
  top: 27,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 20,
  right: 20
},
header: {
  spacing: 10,
  html: {
    template: 'work_order_pdf/header.html.erb'
  }
},
footer: {
  spacing: 5,
  html: {
    template: 'work_order_pdf/footer.html.erb'
  }
}
```

Error in log :-

```
RuntimeError (Error: Failed to execute:
["/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--orientation", "Landscape", "--page-size", "Legal", "--margin-top", "27", "--margin-bottom", "40", "--margin-left", "20", "--margin-right", "20", "--header-spacing", "10", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20151126-3990-ttmmjg.html", "--footer-spacing", "5", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20151126-3990-6tmvq3.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20151126-3990-1r6mnm6.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20151126-3990-10ir53b.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: �~: not found
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: cannot create ��@����@/0��I8
ik�O@�ݦ��O��w�[�@
                         `�n��@9���u{go���W�/�0/���o�C}��i�PAi����k�: Directory nonexistent
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf:ELF: not found
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 3: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
):
```

Comment: Edit the question with the complete command that you gave. Most probably, you forgot to provide the input HTML files and/or the output path to PDF that you want generated. Refer to [instructions](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: Follow the complete steps [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

Comment: I have follow all steps @Prashant4224

Comment: look through code @PrahladYeri

Comment: The error should point you to the specific line causing the problem.  What is it?

Comment: Btw, a much tidier way to write this `"Project_#{Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y").gsub(',','').gsub(' ','_')}.pdf"` is `"Project_#{Time.now.strftime("%B_%d_%Y")}.pdf"`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and error is on - render pdf: "Project_#{Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y").gsub(',','').gsub(' ','_')}.pdf - this line @MaxWilliams

Comment: Please add your stack trace to your question as an edit.

Comment: See the error message @MaxWilliams

Comment: What's all that crazy character encoding stuff?  (��W�/�0/���o�C}�) - that looks like the sort of thing you see when a file contains utf8 chars but is parsed as a different encoding.

Comment: It comes in error message.. I dnt even know the meaning of it.. Is it a reason of error?? @MaxWilliams

Comment: just try `render pdf: "some_name"` then use .html.erb instead pdf.erb for template option

Comment: It means that whatever is processing the data is expecting it to be formatted one way and it's actually formatted a different way.  For example, utf8 (2 byte) data might appear like that if you read it as single-byte text, or it might be that it's trying to read a binary file as if it's a text file.  It might be a symptom of the problem rather than the cause.

Comment: ok thank for comment and my problem is solved now @MaxWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you give the path to the binary in the controller. I think you need to run `rails generate wicked_pdf` and put the binary path in the initializer.